# Custom Checkout Page for Woocommerce in Timber

Tags: woocommerce, twig, themes, timber

I create my custom theme like described in the docs:
https://timber.github.io/docs/guides/woocommerce/

When I now try to create a custom checkout page, this page doesn't call woocommerce.php. Any ideas how to achieve that?

Answer (score 0):

Woocommerce template overriding is done like so:

yourtheme/woocommerce/checkout/form-checkout.php

I am still not sure, why I can't handle form-checkout via woocommerce.php.